# MS SQL - Variable in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I've been wondering if it's possible to declare and set a variable within the definition of another variable.
For example:

```
declare @variable varchar(250)

set @variable =

'INSERT INTO [BLAH] (Nope, Hype, Friends)
VALUES (declare @value varchar(250) set @value = 'example' exec @value, @value, @value)'

exec @variable
```

I'm probably doing multiple really basic mistakes here - just trying to understand as much as fast as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can declare a set of variable inside a variable: doing like this.

```
DECLARE @variable varchar(max)
SET @variable =
'declare @value varchar(max) = ''example''
Insert into BLAH
values(@value,@value)'
EXEC (@variable)
```

Here we simply declared a variable `@value` inside another variable `@variable`

Answer (score 1):

it can be done as below.

```
declare @variable varchar(800)

set @variable =

' declare @value varchar(10) = ''example''
 INSERT INTO [BLAH] (Nope, Hype, Friends)
 VALUES ( @value, @value, @value)'

exec @variable
```

Also get a knowledge of SQL injection before you work with dynamic sql.